# how to create an array list of objects in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I want to create an arraylist of objects in JSP.
And after that, want to loop through the list objects.
can some one please help me in creating it.

Comment: If you know how to do in java , you should already know about how to do in JSP.

Answer (score 2):

Create the `ArrayList` at servlet set it as attribute, and iterate it on JSP using `<c:forEach>`

**Servlet**

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
list.add(foo1);
list.add(foo2);
list.add(foo3);
request.setAttaribute("fooList", list);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

---

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="foo">
 <tr>
  <td><c:out value="${foo.name}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${foo.age}" /></td>
 </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Note: `name` and `age` are two properties of `Foo` with proper accessor methods

Comment: can we create the list in hello.jsp itself?

Comment: @user1581636 there is a way you can embed Java code directly in your JSP. It's called scriptlets. Just create a tag like this `<% /*Java code goes here*/ %>` and you're done. However, using this technique is strongly discouraged. Scriptlets have been virtually replaced by the JSP Expression Language since JSTL 1.0. Also, mixing business and presentation logic makes your code unreadable.